# Why does Vim make certain object keys yellow by default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, sails.js

I use Vim as my terminal editor and one of the things I noticed was that it marks certain words such as 'status' yellow by default. Here's a screenshot:

[image: vim yellow]

I'm little confused because I'm not sure whether it's suggesting that I don't use that word in my model object?

Comment: Is this a file that was saved already with a .js name or one that has been unnamed?

Comment: hi :-) it was saved with a .js ext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim will highlight keywords it recognizes as different colors. While it is possible to use them in some contexts you won't be able to use them in other contexts. Therefore, it is generally recommended that you do not use these reserved words for variables and identifiers in your programs. To see a full list of JavaScript reserved words you can look here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: ah excellent, thank you - did not know of the JS reserved words prior you linking to the resource, left the 'status' word out of my model :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. This makes it very easy to investigate the source of the highlighting - just press `<F1>` when on the element.